# Finding last login date before purchase

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that lists login dates and purchase dates, with the following columns:

```
customerid, Datetime, type
```

where type is of an enumerated format and either "purchase" or "login".

I would like to obtain a list of all purchases, accompanied by the last login date of that person before that purchase.

```
customerid, purchasedatetime, lastloginbeforepurchase
```

I have considered inner joins, cross apply and several other ways, but can't find a good solution.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] one line of `create ...` some lines of ìnsert...`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some details to be able to offer much in the way of help here. Some sample data and desired output would go a LONG way to improving this question. Here is an excellent place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

You could search for the last login with an `outer apply`:

```
select  purchase.customerid
,       purchase.[datetime] as purchasedatetime
,       login.[datetime] as lastloginbeforepurchase
from    YourTable purchase
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    YourTable login
        where   login.customerid = purchase.customerid
                and login.[datetime] < purchase.[datetime]
        order by
                login.[datetime] desc
        ) login
```